# jquery ui datepicker not working on appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, jquery-ui-datepicker

hi i want to show datepicker on appended div but its only affect on first load div.
whenver i try to append div on appended div datepicker not work.

here is my code.

```
$("body").on("focus", ".datepickers", function() {
    var $context = $(this).parents('.entry_day_plan');
    $($(this), $context).datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            //$("#cal4").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var controlForm = $('.controls_day_plan:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry_day_plan:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
        newEntry.find('input').val('hello');
        controlForm.find('.entry_day_plan:not(:last) .btn-add').removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
        newEntry.find(".datepickers").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
        $(this).parents('.entry_day_plan:first').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

and here is a html code...

```
<div class="panel-body dayplan">
    <!--Day Plan-->

    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
        <label class="control-label" for="field1">Please add Day Plan </label>
        <div class="controls_day_plan">
            <div class="entry_day_plan input-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputnumber"> Excursion Name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="itnryname[]" class=" form-control form_line_only" placeholder="EXCURSIONS NAME">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputnumber"> Insert Dates </label>
                    <input type="text" name="itndate[]" class="datepickers form-control form_line_only dateit" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputnumber"> Insert Day </label>
                    <select name="itnday[]" class="form_line_only form-control ">
                        <option>Monday</option>
                        <option>Tuesday</option>
                        <option>Wednesday</option>
                        <option>Thursday</option>
                        <option>Friday</option>
                        <option>Saturday</option>
                        <option>Sunday</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputnumber"> Pickup From </label>
                    <input type="text" name="itnpickfrom[]" class=" form-control form_line_only" placeholder="HOTEL">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputnumber"> Pickup Time </label>
                    <input type="text" name="itnpick[]" class="time timepiker form-control form_line_only" placeholder="6:30 AM">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputnumber"> Dropoff </label>
                    <input type="text" name="itndrop[]" class="time timepiker form-control form_line_only" placeholder="7:00 PM">
                </div>

                <span class="input-group-btn day_plan pull-left">
                    <button class="btn btn-success  btn-add add_col" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </button>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <small>(Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another Day Plan)</small> </div>
```

can anyone tell me how i add datepicker and get value of it ion appended div.

it is already work on first load div but not working on appended div input...
all appended input have a same class..anything i am doing wrong?please suggest me..

here is jsfiidle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/milan9898/46bmL3hd/)

thanks

Comment: Provide a working fiddle link with your question..If you can.!

Comment: if u can provide a fiddle or snippet. it would be better..

Comment: ok i ll update in 2 min

Comment: here is jsfiddel https://jsfiddle.net/milan9898/46bmL3hd/

Comment: on load time "Insert Dates" datepicker working fine whenever click on add button than datepicker not working on second "Insert Dates".. value change also first input. sry for poor english.

Comment: It's working perfectly Okay...on apending next div..! Take a look closely..!

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/2769/ all is working well, your code only

Comment: Besides what error are you getting in your console window???

Comment: @Deep3015 on your jsfiidle when select forst datepicker work fine than append div and check on second datepicker its not getting date perfect

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai i cant getting any error in console..

Comment: @MilanParekh : Ahaa...that is the problem because you are just appending the same div you need to have different input id's or names etc so that all inputs are not connected to each other as for now all of your div inputs I think have the same name...!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai yup i think also to particular id for datepicker but how do i do that on append because its generate whole div again..and i am not master in js,.thanks please help

Comment: oh thanks you so much. @UmairShahYousafzai you are so help full... i am waiting.thank u so much

Comment: Ahaa...so you got your answer..!

Comment: yup @UmairShahYousafzai... but thank you so much for quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this [pen](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/wgVJLO)

```
var datePickerOption = {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {}
}

$("body").on("focus", ".datepickers", function() {
    var $context = $(this).parents('.entry_day_plan');
    $($(this), $context).datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {}
    });
});

var count = 0;
$(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        count++;
        var controlForm = $('.controls_day_plan:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry_day_plan:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input.datepickers').val('').attr('id', 'input_' + count).datepicker(datePickerOption);
        controlForm.find('.entry_day_plan:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
        newEntry.find(".datepickers").removeClass('hasDatepicker');


    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e){
            $(this).parents('.entry_day_plan:first').remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: you are awesome bro. thank you so much very help full.. :)

Comment: @MilanParekh Pleasure is all mine :), You can upvote too ;)